# Can I configure a touchpad to act as modifier keys in some circumstances?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, touchpad, xinput

I have Debian and use Emacs a lot. I have an idea which could help me in using modifier keys.
Currently I just switch the touchpad off when using Emacs, with this command:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

But how about if I could somehow map the touchpad to "hold" the ctrl key if I hold my left palm with a bit higher pressure, and "hold" alt key if I hold my right palm with a bit higher pressure?

I am using an Asus n76, and the touchpad just seems to be the perfect ergonomic solution to this problem.

I used `evtest` to see what parameters I get when moving my fingers across the touchpad. I see values like:

```
ABS_MT_POSITION_X
ABS_MT_POSITION_Y
ABS_MT_PRESSURE
....
```

So all I need to do is somehow set that if `ABS_MT_POSITION_X` is larger than some value (for instance half width of the touchpad), and if `ABS_MT_PRESSURE` is larger than some value (whichever I see fit), the computer should "hold" the ALT or CTRL key accordingly.

This functionality should be when the touchpad is "turned off", and is not moving the mouse. But I should be able to turn the touchpad back on, and use it normally when I need to.

Since I am still fairly new to Linux, I would appreciate some help in how I could achieve this. Any ideas?